# Angular 2+ Lazy Loading Child routes not working

Tags: angular, lazy-loading

My implementation is as follows:

App Routes :

```
export const AppRoutes: Routes = [
    {
    path: 'external',
    loadChildren: './_Layouts/external-layout/external-layout.module#ExternalLayoutModule'
  }]
```

external Routes:

```
export const ExternalRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: ExternalComponent, pathMatch: 'full', canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'programmes', component: ProgrammesComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
];
```

The issue is when the url is
**localhost:4200/external**
it works fine

But when it is
**localhost:4200/programmes**  OR
**localhost:4200/external/programmes**

It is not working at all, What i am missing?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Are you getting any sort of error? What version of Angular?

Also, I think in later versions the loadChildren syntax is as follows:

```
    loadChildren: () => import('./items/items.module').then(m => m.ItemsModule)
```

See more here: https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules

Comment: Dear Ollie, I am using Angular 7, and no there is no error

Comment: You need to make `{ path: 'programmes', component: ProgrammesComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] }` as a child route in your routing module from `external-layout.module`

Comment: Dear smithnblack, I have already tried but not successful

Comment: When i make routes empty it works, but thats not i required: 

*export const AppRoutes: Routes = [
    {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: './_Layouts/external-layout/external-layout.module#ExternalLayoutModule'
  }]*